Biblatex verbose style same citation on number
I am using biblatex with verbose style.
I would like that the same citation key does not create two different foot notes with different numbers (with the second one showing: see Mr xxx). Specifically I would like that subsequent citations point back to the one which cites an item for the first time.
Is it possible? This would save conspicuous amounts of space in my document that is quite space constrained.
Follows a MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[giveninits=true,abbreviate=true,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false,style=verbose-inote, mincitenames=2,maxcitenames=2,date=short,backend=biber,    doi=false]{biblatex} \addbibresource{biblio.bib} \renewcommand{\cite}{\autocite} \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8bp}{1em}\selectfont} \begin{document}

Forza\cite{einstein} Napoli\cite{dirac} Sempre\cite{einstein}

\end{document}

The biblio.bib file is:
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}



Are you saying you want all the subsequent footnotes to point back to the one which cites an item for the first time? Anyway, could you provide a Minimal Working Example, please?

Yes indeed, I have just added a MWE. I can upload a photo of the document if needed.

Alright, if your intention is merely to reference the footnote number without creating a new footnote, then these commands are all you need.
\DeclareFieldFormat{textsuperscript}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

This command establishes a format that mandates a specific field to be written as a superscript.
\newbibmacro{cite:superseen}{%
    \printtext[textsuperscript]{%
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

This macro tracks the footnote number of the first citation.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifciteseen%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:superseen}}%
        {\footnote{\usebibmacro{footcite}}}}%
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

Finally, we modify the citation command \cite so that it generates a footnote at its first appearance and, if the condition \ifciteseen is true, writes the number of the first footnote.
Here are you the MWE back.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,
            giveninits=true,
            abbreviate=true,
            isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false,doi=false,
            mincitenames=2,maxcitenames=2,
            date=short,
            backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textsuperscript}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\newbibmacro{cite:superseen}{%
    \printtext[textsuperscript]{%
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifciteseen%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:superseen}}%
        {\footnote{\usebibmacro{footcite}}}}%
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author={Einstein, Albert},
    title={Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper},
    titleaddon={({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
    journaltitle={Annalen der Physik},
    volume={322},number={10},year={1905},
    pages={891--921},
    doi={10.1002/andp.19053221004},
    keywords={physics}}

@book{dirac,
    author={Dirac, Paul Adrien Maurice},
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},year={1981},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    keywords={physics}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is a content note.\footnote{Content.}

This is a reference note: the first one.\cite{dirac}

Other reference notes.\cite[pre][post]{dirac,einstein}

This is another content note.\footnote{Content.}

I repeat the reference notes.\cite{einstein,dirac}

I repeat one reference note.\cite{einstein}

I repeat one reference note.\cite{dirac}

The \textit{\textbackslash footcite} command is still the same. \footcite{einstein}

I repeat one reference note.\footcite{einstein}
\end{document}

This time, I tried to adhere more closely to the style guide.
I apologise for misunderstanding your question.

Cheers - this worked very well, thank you!
The only note I have relates to the use of \multicitedelim: I renewed it so that it is in superscript text as follows: \renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\textsuperscript{,}}

I think you are trying to implement the ISO 690 citation style, at least as described by Roberto Lesina in his Il Nuovo Manuale di Stile (1994, 2nd edition, p. 264). I haven't got any copy of the ISO standard text, so I can not confirm.
Specifically, Lesina distinguishes between the «in full» references, the «short» references and the subsequent references in a «cross-ref form» (p. 261). According to his interpretation of the ISO 690 standard, the «in full» references are exclusive to the bibliography; the «short» references (I thinl coinciding with a simple author-title style by the biblatex package) are used for the first citation; the subsequent references in a «cross-ref form» are used for following citations.
There would be the biblatex-iso690 style in CTAN, but the authors didn't consider this way to cite either.
It doesn't matter, anyway.
Indeed, it's certainly possible to cite complying with your style.
You need to be able to cross-reference directly to footnotes.
So, you have to set someway to tracking citations made exclusively in footnotes. Therefore, you need to utilise the \iffootnote command: it belongs to the biblatex package and tracks without discriminating between the exact citation command (i.e. it makes no difference whether you are in a footnote environment and use the \cite command, or in the main text environment and use the \footcite one).
You have to track in order to use the \ifciteseen command. It seems to be the only one of interest to you: I don't think you are interested in options such as those which print «op. cit.» or «loc. cit.» strings, i.e. tracking whether a citation is the same as the previous one, etc. I see that you simply want to see if a citation has already been made.
Therefore, you only need to decide how to implement this, as you have the tools and conditions. Given the style you have chosen, namely the verbose-inote one, I recommend customising the footcite macro.
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \ifciteseen
        {\iffootnote%
            {\printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\footrefdelim}%
            \bibstring{seenote}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \printtext{%
            \ref{note:\thefield{entrykey}}}}%
            {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
            {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}}
            {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}
            {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}}
        {\iffootnote%
            {\label{note:\thefield{entrykey}}}%
            {}%
        \usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
        \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}

Firstly, note that, in the true condition of the \ifciteseen command, I added simply a higher level, which makes my intervention valid exclusively within footnotes. In this way, the macro remains effectively unchanged from its original definition for all subsequent citations that are not in footnotes.
Secondly, there is already a string to indicate in the output that the citation is referring to a previous note: it's the {seenote} one.
Thirdly, I ensured that, when the citation of a particular entry is the first in a footnote, a label is created (\label{note:\thefield{entrykey}}). Then, when LaTeX encounters the citation for the second and subsequent times in a footnote, I ensured that this label is recalled (\ref{note:\thefield{entrykey}}). Note that if the very first citation of an entry isn't in a footnote, nothing special happens: LaTeX won't create the label, but it will do so only at the first footnote citation.
Them, I added a special delimiter between the author's name and the seenote string. If you prefer, you can use the \newunit command instead, or you can define a specific delimiter with the \setunit{<>} command. Otherwise, if you like, you can copy my footrefdelim delimiter, just invented in occasion of this answer.
\DeclareDelimFormat{footrefdelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

That's all.

After reading your answer I suspect I may not have explained what I want to achieve well. The goal would -in reference to my MWE- to have only 2 footnotes, and the third citation simply indicate a superscript 1 and hence refer to the Einstin footnote.
Was that what you code tries to achieve?
Moreover, I have issues in compiling the code as there appears to be some error (I am somewhat new to this level of Biblatex)
